# Linux How to htop specific commands

Tags: linux, htop

Linux Centos 6,64

I am using following command for displaying htop in the command column

htop -u command

How do I do for it to show only a specific command which i choose from those running commands list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `htop -u` the parameter is a user name, not a command.

The only option to monitor a specific command is `-p`, but this takes a PID, so the command name must be converted to a PID first, which `pidof` will do.

If more than one instance of a command is running, `pidof` returns a space-separated list of PIDs, but the `-p` option takes a comma-separated list, so the `pidof` output must be converted:

```
htop -p $(pidof command | sed 's/ /,/g')
```

This is best incorporated into a function or script, in which case the command will be:

```
htop -p $(pidof "$1" | sed 's/ /,/g')
```

Although I first think of `sed` for batch editing, in this case the simpler `tr` command could be used:

```
htop -p $(pidof "$1" | tr ' ' ',')
```

Note that GUI system monitors, such as `qps` and `ksysguard`, can filter the output and show specific commands directly (though the text-based filter may also pick up the command name if it happens to appear in the parameter list of another command).

Comment: Hello AFH, thanks for your reply. The commands you suggested came up with following message in here "Error: unknown flag: -p" .

Comment: You must have a different version of `htop`: mine is 2.0.1, as shown by `htop -v`.

Comment: Hello, have updated it, its working now, thank you very much !